# How should I manage the resolution of my image assets to accommodate different sized devices

Tags: android, image, libgdx, textures, resolution

On the first place I want to make clear that I'm not talking about aspect ratio, I'm already using OrthographicCamera with Viewports and them work fine.
My problem is about images resolution, what happens is that if I create an image on Photoshop (lets assume it is a 128x128 .png) and then I put it as a texture in my 128x128 sprite it seems to look fine on my device. Then I try the same screen an another device with a lower resolution and the final effect is quite ugly.
On the other hand if I put an image with an higher resolution (for instance a 512x512 .png texture in a sprite sized as 128x128) it looks ugly on my high-resolution device.
So whatever I do on Photoshop I'm not able to achieve a nice effect on every device.
How can I handle it?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429815/libgdx-textures-quality-on-different-phone-resolutions?rq=1

Comment: The question you linked has found a solution for texture atlas. The user says it was not working with simple textures.  Maybe it could work in my case but it's not the very same argument...

Comment: do you use Texture filters? F.e. LINEAR or NEAREST?

Comment: have a read http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403